# ansibleでnginxのインストールでエラーが起きる。

Tags: aws, ansible, amazon-linux

ansibleのyamlでnginxのインストールを行いたいのですがエラーが出ます。
エラーの発生したyamlの内容を置きますので解消法教えていただけますと幸いです。

main.yml

```
- name: nginx install
  shell:yum install nginx
  args:
    warn: no
```

エラー

```js
fatal: [Client01]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": true,
  "cmd": "yum -y install nginx",
  "delta": "0:00:00.651993",
  "end": "2020-09-05 13:06:43.982719",
  "msg": "non-zero return code",
  "rc": 1,
  "start": "2020-09-05 13:06:43.330726",
  "stderr": "Error: Nothing to do",
  "stderr_lines": [
    "Error: Nothing to do"
  ],
  "stdout": "Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd\nNo package nginx available.\n\n\nnginx is available in Amazon Linux Extra topics \"nginx1.12\" and \"nginx1\"\n\nTo use, run\n# sudo amazon-linux-extras install :topic:\n\nLearn more at\nhttps://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd",
    "No package nginx available.",
    "",
    "",
    "nginx is available in Amazon Linux Extra topics \"nginx1.12\" and \"nginx1\"",
    "",
    "To use, run",
    "# sudo amazon-linux-extras install :topic:",
    "",
    "Learn more at",
    "https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras"
  ]
}
```

他にも以下のようなインストールの方法を試しましたがエラーが出てインストール出来ません。

```
- name: nginx install
  yum:
    name: nginx
    state: latest
```

```
- name: install nginx
  package:
    name: nginx
    state: present
```

Comment: https://qiita.com/3244/items/051a2c44e19ab932dc0f が参考になりそうです。Amazon Linux特有の事情でしょう。

Comment: fuserとpsmiscのパッケージも同様の記述ではインストールできないようです。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージにはどのように対処すればよいか、必要な情報が表示されているように思います。

> nginx is available in Amazon Linux Extra topics "nginx1.12" and "nginx1"
>
> To use, run
>
> ```
> # sudo amazon-linux-extras install :topic:
> ```
>
> Learn more at
> https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras

Amazon Linux では一部のアプリケーション (パッケージ) が "Amazon Linux Extras" という扱いで、これらをインストールするには `amazon-linux-extras` コマンドを使う必要があります。

Nginx をインストールしたい場合には、"nginx1.12" または "nginx1" をパッケージ名として指定すればよさそうです。

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
```